# What could cause errors in combined javascript that runs fine when loaded separately?

Tags: javascript

I've written a server-side utility that is meant to manage javascript page dependencies. During development, it serves the javascript as separate files (embeds individual script tags in the order defined), and in production mode it reads the files, minifies them (Google Closure in Whitespace only mode), and embeds them via a single script tag.

For the moment, I've turned off minification to eliminate that variable...so all it is doing is joining the files together with a newline between each.

When I go to production mode, I get spurious problems in a number of the files that are embedded.

So, does anyone have any ideas of what problems I could be causing by serving a set of files as a single, concatenated file? I'm at a loss.

For those wanting more detail:

I am certain the order is correct.

The list of files in question is rather large for this example, but include jquery, angular, controllers, jquery dnd fileupload, controllers, etc.

I get "Uncaught Type Error: undefined is not a function" at this line of the combo:

```
(function(b){b.support.touch="ontouchend" in document;if(!b.support.touch){return;}var c=b.ui.mouse.prototype,e=c._mouseInit,a;function d(g,h){if(g.originalEvent.touches.length>1){return;}g.preventDefault();var i=g.originalEvent.changedTouches[0],f=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");f.initMouseEvent(h,true,true,window,1,i.screenX,i.screenY,i.clientX,i.clientY,false,false,false,false,0,null);g.target.dispatchEvent(f);}c._touchStart=function(g){var f=this;if(a||!f._mouseCapture(g.originalEvent.changedTouches[0])){return;}a=true;f._touchMoved=false;d(g,"mouseover");d(g,"mousemove");d(g,"mousedown");};c._touchMove=function(f){if(!a){return;}this._touchMoved=true;d(f,"mousemove");};c._touchEnd=function(f){if(!a){return;}d(f,"mouseup");d(f,"mouseout");if(!this._touchMoved){d(f,"click");}a=false;};c._mouseInit=function(){var f=this;f.element.bind("touchstart",b.proxy(f,"_touchStart")).bind("touchmove",b.proxy(f,"_touchMove")).bind("touchend",b.proxy(f,"_touchEnd"));e.call(f);};})(jQuery);
```

which follows some other file embeds that generate global vars:

```
var FocusElementDirective = function() {
...
}
var DirectiveApplier = function(){
...
}
var AgeCalculator = function(){
...
}
```

Another one: when I trigger an "add" event in the angular plugin for jquery fileupload, it gives Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'scope'. The line it is pointing to is within the jquery fileupload angular module (line 89 of version 9.0.5):

```
        add: function (e, data) {
            if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                return false;
            }
            var scope = data.scope(), // this line
```

Comment: Is it maybe concatenating them in the wrong order?  Can you identify a single problem of the many encountered and focus just on the cause of that one problem?

Comment: Please post the specific error messages

Comment: Do you have file-level strict mode in any of the files?

Comment: @Cuberto There are strict sections, but not in the global space. Good thinking, though...that was one I had not thought to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found it, and it turned out to be something ultra-simple...so simple that I pulled my hair out for hours looking for something technical:

I had a duplicate.

When loaded as  tags, the browser only bothered to load the file once. When concatenated, the code was actually duplicated. This led to all sorts of weirdness (e.g. event handlers were getting hooked to the wrong version of things).

Coming from a compiled language background, I kinda would expect some duplicate symbol kinds of notifications...ah dynamic languages.

Answer (score 1):

Just happening upon this and the first thing that comes to mind is that it could be something to do with global variables, one of those things Crockford complains about as a weakness of javascript.

For a quick description:

[JavaScript global variables & self-invoking anonymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045466/javascript-global-variables-self-invoking-anonymous-functions)

Just off the top of my head.